# Return custom Model with list of models HttpGet

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Instead of sending multiple HTTPget requests to get all data from db, I want to send one request and return all info. I have, for example, several models:

```
public class Model1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Model3
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Food{ get; set; }
    }
```

I need to return list of these models (List< Model1>, List< Model2>, List< Model3>) to client.

I create a new model

```
public class Allinone
    {
    public List<Model1> Model1= new List<Model1>();
    public List<Model2> Model2= new List<Model2>();
    public List<Model3> Model3= new List<Model3>();
    }
```

In controller I have this:

```
    [HttpGet("updateall")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAll(int clientid)
        {
            Allinone model = new Allinone();
            
             model.model1 = db.where(....);
             model.model1 = db.where(....);
             model.model1 = db.where(....);


            return Ok(model);

        }
```

In debug mode, I can see the model is properly populated with data from the database, but on client-side (in Postman and in Xamarin client app) I can't read the content. In postman, I get only empty string {}.

I the Xamarin client app I have the same models as in asp net core, but the content is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you don't need to init list in your AllInOne class, just make it like this:

```
public class AllInOne
    {
    public List<Model1> Models1 {get; set;}
    public List<Model2> Models2 {get; set;}
    public List<Model3> Models3 {get; set;}
    }
```

Try to change your action signature to this:

```
        [Route("UpdateAll/{clientId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AllInOne>> UpdateAll(int clientid)
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, I tried as you suggested, just insted of IActionResult I used ActionResult because with IAction got some error, but still the same problem, I get only empty string {} as result.

Comment: I put some changes.  Pls try this in Postman for test

Comment: Thank you for solving the problem really quickly :). The problem was the wrong initialization of the list. I never know if it should be initialized or not. After I changed as you suggested, it now works (it also works with [httpget ("updateall")].)

Comment: Thanks for a feedback. I am happy that I could help you.